# ZF2 with Doctrine 2 - Injecting dependencies in entities

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 in a Zend Framework 2 application. Is there any way using ZF2 to inject dependencies into entities returned by Doctrine? Entities are constructed by Doctrine when retrieved from the database. So far as I know to inject dependencies in ZF2 I need to instantiate entities using Service Locator. I cannot see how I can integrate that with Doctrine without having to modify Doctrines code base. The only feasible solution I can see right now is to write a small service which takes the result returned from Doctrine and injects the required dependencies. Is there a more elegant solution?

Best Regards 
Christian

Comment: What exactly do you want to inject? I can't think of a case where it makes sense to inject something into an entity. I'm sure there is a way to do what you want that fits in the concept.

Comment: I took another direction in the meantime. The things I wanted to delegate to the entities themselves are now delegated to a service, which manages the entities. So there is no need any more to inject something into entities

Answer (score 16):

Look into the Doctrine [EventManager](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html), in particular, the [postLoad](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) lifecycle event, which is fired by the EventManager every time an entity is loaded from the database.

To hook it all into ZF2, you would need to do a couple of things.

First, write a Doctrine-Flavored event listener:

```
<?php
class InjectStuffListener {
   private $sl;

   public function __construct($serviceLocator){
      $this->sl = $serviceLocator;
   }

   public function postLoad($eventArgs){
       $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity;
       $entity->setThingToBeInjected($this->sl->get('some.thing'));
   }
}
```

Then, in someplace like some Module.php (maybe there's a better place than onBootstrap, but whatever):

```
<?php
public function onBootstrap(){
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $em = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $dem = $em->getEventManager();
    $dem->addEventListener(array( \Doctrine\ORM\Events::postLoad ), new InjectStuffListener( $sm ) );

}
```

Comment: Yes but I can not see how I could connect this with the ZF2 service locator/service manager to inject dependencies which are managed by ZF2. The entity itself does not know about the service locator because it is not instantiated through the service locator.

Comment: @griesi - see my edit for some example code that initializes listeners and attaches them to doctrine's EventManager during ZF2 bootstrap.

Comment: Thank´s this is exactly I was searching for