# Set created by user reference on PrePersist in doctrine entity in zf2 project

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfcuser

In my zf2 project, I have doctrine 2 entities that reference the user entity as created by as the following:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $createdBy;
```

and I want to set this reference in the `PrePersist`, how can I do that?
I tried the following (I don't know if it is right):

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist */
public function prePersist() {
    if ($this->createdBy === null) {
        $session = new \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session;
        $userId = $session->read();
        if ($userId !== null) {
            $this->createdBy = $userId;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid User");
        }
    }
}
```

but the main problem is that the `$userId` is an integer, and `createdBy` must hold the reference of the user not the user ID.

is there a better way to do that? if no, how can I get the reference instead of the user ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly accessing your session storage, you might configuring a `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` to handle your authenticated identity.

Then you could set your `Namespace\For\Entity\User` as your AuthenticationService identity and inject the authentication service via setter injection (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336089/1312094) about hooking into Doctrine lifecycle events).

Then you should be able to do this:

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist */
public function prePersist() {
    if (empty($this->createdBy)) {
        $this->setCreatedBy($this->getAuthenticationService()->getIdentity());
    }
}
```

...or you could add a $loggedInUser property to your entity, and inject the logged in User directly, instead of creating a dependency on the AuthenticationService (or session storage). This is probably the better way, because it simplifies your tests:

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist */
public function prePersist() {
    if (empty($this->createdBy)) {
        $this->setCreatedBy($this->getLoggedInUser());
    }
}
```

Note that I got rid of the type-checking in your prePersist method by using setters, because then you can handle that via type-hinting in your setters like this:

```
public function setAuthenticationService(\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService $authenticationService){/** do stuff */};

public function setLoggedInUser(\Namespace\For\Entity\User $user){/** do stuff */};

public function setCreatedBy(\Namespace\For\Entity\User $user){/** do stuff */};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me even more than I wanted... :)